# multiple objectives in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, data-science, shiny-server

Hello I am relatively new to shiny . I am working on a basic app that takes the portfolio returns of different stocks and does PCA on those portfolio returns the application is supposed to show a table of the different principle components and print a summary of the principle components as well but it s only showing the table and not the summary of the principle components .
here is my code

```
library(shiny)
server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$print<-renderTable({
    ticker<-c(input$STOCK1, input$STOCK2, input$STOCK3, input$STOCK4)
    portfolioPrice <- NULL
    for(ticker in ticker) {
      portfolioPrice <- cbind(portfolioPrice,
                              getSymbols.yahoo(ticker,  periodicity = 'daily', auto.assign=FALSE)[,6])
    }
    poty=na.omit(ROC(portfolioPrice))
    op=prcomp(poty, scale. = T)
    dadsa=op$rotation
    axz=as.table(dadsa)

    return(axz)
  })

  output$out<-renderPrint({
    ticker<-c(input$STOCK1, input$STOCK2, input$STOCK3, input$STOCK4)
    portfolioPrice <- NULL
    for(ticker in ticker) {
      portfolioPrice <- cbind(portfolioPrice,
                              getSymbols.yahoo(ticker,  periodicity = 'daily', auto.assign=FALSE)[,6])
    }
    poty=na.omit(ROC(portfolioPrice))
    op=prcomp(poty, scale. = T)


    waps=summary(op)
    return(waps)
  })







} # the server

ui = basicPage(
  textInput("STOCK1", "STOCK 1","AAL"),
  textInput("STOCK2","STOCK 2","NULL" ),
  textInput("STOCK3", "STOCK 3" ,"NULL" ),
  textInput("STOCK4","STOCK4"),
  tableOutput("print")
  textOutput("out")
) # the user interface

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) # perform app launch
```

here is a picture of the app as it stands as you can see it takes the stocks and shows the table of principle components  [image]

but the app  is not printing the summary of the principle components which is supposed to look like this

[image]

please help I will be incredibly grateful and I'm sure this will help other coders trying to learn shiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `verbatimTextOutput` instead of `textoutput` :

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$print<-renderTable({
    ticker<-c(input$STOCK1, input$STOCK2, input$STOCK3, input$STOCK4)
    portfolioPrice <- NULL
    for(ticker in ticker) {
      portfolioPrice <- cbind(portfolioPrice,
                              getSymbols.yahoo(ticker,  periodicity = 'daily', auto.assign=FALSE)[,6])
    }
    poty=na.omit(ROC(portfolioPrice))
    op=prcomp(poty, scale. = T)
    dadsa=op$rotation
    axz=as.table(dadsa)

    return(axz)
  })

  output$out<-renderPrint({}
    ticker<-c(input$STOCK1, input$STOCK2, input$STOCK3, input$STOCK4)
    portfolioPrice <- NULL
    for(ticker in ticker) {
      portfolioPrice <- cbind(portfolioPrice,
                              getSymbols.yahoo(ticker,  periodicity = 'daily', auto.assign=FALSE)[,6])
    }
    poty=na.omit(ROC(portfolioPrice))
    op=prcomp(poty, scale. = T)
    waps=summary(op)
    return(waps)
  })
} # the server

ui = basicPage(
  textInput("STOCK1", "STOCK 1","AAL"),
  textInput("STOCK2","STOCK 2","NULL" ),
  textInput("STOCK3", "STOCK 3" ,"NULL" ),
  textInput("STOCK4","STOCK4"),
  tableOutput("print"),
  verbatimTextOutput ("out")  #Use `verbatimTextOutput` instead of `textoutput`
) # the user interface

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```